# third party ads provider In UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, ads

are there any good ads provider for the Uwp app
any suggestions
I was looking for the same I found ad jumbo but there is nothing about any Video add and rewarded ads.

Comment: Please don't ask questions that are categorically off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> third party ads provider In UWP

Please check this [reminder](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/db8d44cb-1381-47f7-94d3-c6ded3fea36f/microsoft-ad-monetization-platform-shut-down-as-of-june-1st?forum=aiamgr), *we have shut down the Microsoft Ad Monetization services for Windows UWP apps per the sunset announcement made January 2020*

*To help Windows UWP app/game developers continue to monetize using Ads, we have partnered with the third party Ad providers, such as RISE Pubfinity Vungle*

Please refer above [reminder](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/db8d44cb-1381-47f7-94d3-c6ded3fea36f/microsoft-ad-monetization-platform-shut-down-as-of-june-1st?forum=aiamgr) to get more info.